# LaTeX figures in two column

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

Is there a convenient way to place a `figure*` at the end of the current page instead of taking up the entire next page in the `twocolumn` environment? Placement modifiers `[Hb]` do not work.

Answer (score 18):

Try the [stfloats](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sttools) package.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure*}[b]
\centering\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}
\caption{A nice figure}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [`dblfloatfix` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/dblfloatfix) also provides placement specifiers in `twocolumn` format, although it's usually delayed for at least one page:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}% http://ctan.org/pkg/dblfloatfix
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[b]
  \centering\rule{.7\textwidth}{.2\textwidth}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

In the above example, note how the first is placed at the beginning of the document (page 1) and requested at the `b`ottom, while it actually is displayed at the bottom of page 2. However, placement may still depend on the size of the included image.

Note that it should not be used in conjunction with the [`stfloats` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/stfloats).

Answer (score 0):

`[Hb]` makes no sense as a placement modifier – `[H]` can only be used alone, and means “place it HERE, period” (and requires the `float` package).

If you want to place it at the bottom, use just `[b]`. If LaTeX thinks it knows better than you, try `[b!]` to make LaTeX try harder. If that still doesn’t work you’re essentially out of luck.

Comment: None of the placement modifiers do anything in two column.

Comment: Ah drat, I forgot about that. My comment still stands in general though. Furthermore, for multicolumn figures see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=mcfloat

Comment: Yes, that's true. The problem isn't the horizontal location, size or shape of the image. It's that the image is forced on a new page when there is plenty of room for it on the previous one. I find it hard to believe that there is no way around this. Are there better packages to use than multicol? I'm relatively new to Latex. Thanks.

Comment: @Chet I’m not sure. LaTeX’ figure placement often annoys me, not only with multicols.