# How to put a double-column equation at the bottom of the current page with figure float in LyX?

Tags: floats, equations, lyx

I am using the IEEE Transaction class in LyX. With a figure float, I was able to put a long equation spanning two columns at the top of the next page, as shown in the pictures below

[image]
[image]

My questions are: 1. How do I place the long equation at the bottom of the page 
and 2. How do I let it appear in the same page (not the next page) where the equation is defined?

Do I need to load some packages? I prefer to still use the figure float in LyX where the labeling and numbering features still work for this long equation than a solution completely using ERT. In that case, I think the numbering and labeling of equations become more cumbersome.

Comment: Yes you need to load an extra package, by default such double column objects can not be placed at the bottom.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66467/15925 for some package choices.